# ObjectDataSource and null parameters

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, coalesce, vwdexpress

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2008 EE using a Dataset (.xsd) to develop an invoicing application and i'm having trouble creating a custom search query.
I have an ObjectDataSource that expects 4 ControlParameters, like so:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsInvoices" runat="server" SelectMethod="getInvoices" TypeName="bllInvoice">
    <SelectParameters>            
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpProjectsFilter" Type="Int32" Name="intProject" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />       
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpMonthsFilter" Type="Int32" Name="intMonth" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpYearFilter" Type="Int32" Name="intYear" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpStatusFilter" Type="Int32" Name="intStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

For each of these controls (dropdowns) I have a default value of "" (=empty string) and I have added the option ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" for each parameter. 
The query that is behind the ObjectDataSource is this one:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE (YEAR(invoices.invoice_date) = COALESCE (@year, YEAR(invoices.invoice_date))) 
AND (invoices.fk_project_id = COALESCE (@projectID, invoices.fk_project_id)) 
AND (MONTH(invoices.invoice_date) = COALESCE (@month, MONTH(invoices.invoice_date))) 
AND (invoices.invoice_status = COALESCE (@statusID, invoices.invoice_status))
```

Using COALESCE, I'm basically saying to ignore any of the 4 parameters if they are null and to return all rows.

The problem is that this query doesn't return any rows, unless I specify a value for each of the 4 parameters, essentially debunking the whole purpose of this custom search.

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the MSSQL documentation:

> ISNULL and COALESCE though equivalent, can behave differently. An expression involving ISNULL with non-null parameters is considered to be NOT NULL, while expressions involving COALESCE with non-null parameters is considered to be NULL.

So try changing your query to look like this:

```
select ...
  from ...
 where year(invoices.invoice_date)  = isnull(@year, year(invoices.invoice_date))
   and invoices.fk_project_id       = isnull(@projectID, invoices.fk_project_id)
   and month(invoices.invoice_date) = isnull(@month, month(invoices.invoice_date))
   and invoices.invoice_status      = isnull(@statusID, invoices.invoice_status)
```

If that doesn't work, use SQL Profiler to check exactly what is being passed to your `SELECT` when it's invoked.

Comment: Thanks Ian, but I initially tried this with ISNULL and it didn't work. Also, I want to avoid using ISNULL since it's only supported in T-SQL, and who know we might change our DB provider in the future.

Comment: In that case I can only suggest SQL Profiler :). I have experienced issues with `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` being ignored in Mono, but I doubt that's applicable to your situation.

Comment: Have a look at the SQL in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493458/search-based-on-matched-criteria/1493643#1493643 which I think will do what you want and may be a little more portable.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my own problem.
As it turns out, the ControlParameters did not return NULL (as in a dbnull value), but the actual number 0. I have adapted my SQL statement to the following:

```
select ...  from ... 
where ((@year=0) OR (year(invoices.invoice_date)=@year)) 
and ((@projectID=0) OR (invoices.fk_project_id=@projectID))   
and ((@month=0) OR (month(invoices.invoice_date)=@month))
and ((@statusID=0) OR (invoices.invoice_status=@statusID))
```

This way, if a ControlParameter has a value of 0, it will still return all rows.
Hope this can help somebody.

Regards,
Stijn